# Create a class with same object property values

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege

Imagine we have a Classes A and B and C.

Imagine we have two object Properties “hasC” and “hasB”

how can we have a class property restriction, so is it says

A is subclass of

hasB min 1 B ("which has" hasC min 1 C)

hasC min 1 C

Where the value of hasC.C is the same for the B instance and the instance of this class A.

Comment: Le'ts call the value of hasC.C `c` for convenience. Do you know `c` in advance? If so you can make a oneOf(`c`) class and use it as a restriction.

Answer (score 0):

> Where the value of hasC.C is the same for the B instance and the instance of this class A.

This kind of axiom isn't usually possible in OWL.  As Ignazio mentioned in a comment, if you have a particular instance of **C** in mind, e.g., **c73**, you can use an enumerated class, like **hasC some {c73}** or the expression **hasC value c73**, but you can't do general "agreement" axioms like this.  For instance, there's no way to define a "diamond hierarchy subclass" as one which has two distinct ancestors that have some common ancestor.